# substract month from timestamp in second

Tags: python, datetime

I would like to substract months from a timestamp in second.  Here is what I'm doing:

```
>>> ts = 1454284800
>>> date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(time.strftime('%Y%m%d', time.gmtime(1454284800)), '%Y%m%d')
>>> date_object
datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 1, 0, 0)
>>> date_substract = date_object - datetime.timedelta(9*365/12.0)
>>> date_substract
datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 3, 6, 0)
>>>
```

It depends on the value for the number of months I want to substract, but for 9 months for exemple, days datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 3, **6**, 0) are wrong.  Is there a better way to substract months, which would only change number of months and not days as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try with `dateutil.relativedelta` module.

Comment: Care to elaborate your goal? A *month* isn't a fixed timespan, but varies with the month in question. Do you want the same day of month but nine months earlier?

Comment: Yes that is it, I only want to change the month value without changing days or something else.

Comment: So what day is nine months before November 30?

Comment: I only want to substract months days will always be 1 actually, if i'm in months 11 and substract 9 months I want to be in months 2 and day 1.

Comment: @khelwood Depends on your notion. `dateutil.relativedelta` clamps to the month end, i.e. *nine months before Nov 30* is either *Feb 28* or *Feb 29*.

Comment: your variable "ts" does it means current time in seconds

Comment: @dhke Not on _my_ notion. On the OP's. That is why I was asking the OP.

Comment: @khelwood Please take that *your* as detached from the addressee meaning "whatever the person having to solve the problem needs".

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @DainDwarf, [`dateutil.relativedelta`](http://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/relativedelta.html) seems to be your friend. It calculates a date relative to another date value.

It handles the tricky cases (e.g. a month before March 31st), but you need to check that the resolution meets your requirements

```
date = datetime.datetime(year=2016, month=3, day=31)
date + dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(date, months=-1)
=> datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 29, 0, 0)
```

Comment: It is a solution but I have to install this module.